# R: throw an error every time I try to index with a factor?

Tags: r, indexing

I don't know if anyone else feels that factors in R are incredibly weird and should behave differently, but anyway, here is the issue:

**The problem**

```
> a = matrix(rnorm(12), nrow=3, dimnames=list(LETTERS[5:7],LETTERS[1:4]))
> b = c("B","C")

> a[,b]
       B          C
E -1.1886578  2.6433882
F -0.9113276  0.8333795
G  1.1922121 -1.9239478
```

If I index `a` with `b`, everything works as expected. If `b` is a factor however, its integer values are used for indexing:

```
> a[,as.factor(b)]
       A          B
E  0.4137923 -1.1886578
F -0.4302323 -0.9113276
G  1.2566591  1.1922121
```

This has been the source of countless issues I was facing, especially since `character`s are often automatically converted into `factor`s, e.g. when putting them in a `data.frame`.

If this conversion happens once and you don't think of it, there is your hard-to-track-down bug.

**A possible? solution**

Globally setting `stringsAsFactors=F` is likely a bad approach because it may break existing code.

Instead, I'd like R to throw an error every time I try to index anything with a factor. The idea was to put something like the code below in my `~/.Rprofile`:

```
`[` = function(X, ...) {
    if (any(is.factor(...)))
        stop("Indexing with factor")
    else
        .Primitive("[")(X, ...)
}
```

The above is not working. I can't seem to find a good solution that does not break `[` in any way except when indexing with factors.

Any ideas?

Comment: I really think that it's way better to understand what a factor is and how it works instead of trying to hack some primitive function. There is nothing "random" in factor and it's up to the programmer to check what kind of object he is using.

Comment: Never claimed it was random, but characters get coerced into factors in a multitude of occasions. This is meant as a guard from indexing with a factor by accident, where checking every instance is needlessly verbose. Where such a thing is handy is e.g. (ad-hoc) data analysis, not software engineering (which no sane person would do in R to begin with).

Comment: If you learn and understand where are this "multitude of occasions", you'd never index with a factor by accident. That's my point. Plus, if you succeed in your hack, you could not run code by other programmers who can properly handle factors.

Comment: Maybe you could tackle that from the other side: Have `as.factor` give a warning when it is called. I advice against messing with the subsetting primitive as your additional check will just make subsetting slow.

Comment: Otherwise, you could hack `matrix`/`as.matrix` to give the return object an additional class `safematrix` and create a method `[.safematrix`, which ["checks if i or j are factor before calling NextMethod"](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19118144#19118144). There might be dragons.

Comment: @nicola, maybe it is better to try and understand the question instead of blaming the OP of not understanding what a factor is

Comment: @FedericoGiorgi I don't think I blamed the OP in any way. Guess the question was clear for me and I offered my solution. OP had two ways of handling this "issue". One was to hack a primitive function and the other was to understand deeply what a factor is. I offered my preference. I bet that if OP had to chance to stick with R in these 2.5 years, he'd never had to face this issue again, since very likely in the meantime he understood what a factor is.

Comment: @nicola I know he understood it because he is sitting next to me

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily for data.frames because there is an existing S3 method:

```
trace("[.data.frame", quote(if (is.factor(j)) warning("Indexing with factor")))
#you could overwrite the method instead of using trace

a = matrix(rnorm(12), nrow=3, dimnames=list(LETTERS[5:7],LETTERS[1:4]))
b = c("B","C")

as.data.frame(a)[,b]
#Tracing `[.data.frame`(as.data.frame(a), , b) on entry 
#           B          C
#E  0.2539326  1.3292468
#F -0.4088534 -0.7554019
#G -1.2535690  0.3149922
as.data.frame(a)[,factor(b)]
#Tracing `[.data.frame`(as.data.frame(a), , factor(b)) on entry 
#           A          B
#E -0.6147412  0.2539326
#F -0.6899518 -0.4088534
#G  1.3720187 -1.2535690
#Warning message:
#  In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Indexing with factor

untrace("[.data.frame")
```

You'd need to do the same for `[<-.data.frame`.

However, I can't offer a solution for matrix subsetting because that is handled by the primitive and I don't think you can/should define a method. Personally, I rarely subset matrices with characters.

Comment: Thank you, that does go in the right direction. I do, however, work mainly with named matrices. For overwriting primitives I agree in general, though I think in the case I mentioned it is justified.

Answer (score 0):

If `b` is a factor, just wrap `as.character()` around it.

```
a[,as.character(factor(b))]
           B        C
E  2.0451415 0.477410
F -0.4739111 1.616437
G -0.2422863 1.791818
```

The numbers are different than yours because you didn't give us a reproducible example. You could use `set.seed()` to make it reproducible in the future.

Comment: The issue is, I don't know *when* I will be indexing with a factor by mistake. This is meant as a guard against it, so I can't wrap every possible combination in `as.character`. The numbers are irrelevant to the example.

Comment: Then just ask, "Is this a factor?" If so, convert it to a character. If not, proceed as normal. For the sake of simplicity, let's make a new object `c` that is the facotrized version of `b`.

Comment: I forgot I can't use code blocks in a comment. Anyway, make `c <- factor(b)` then use something like `a[,if(is.factor(c)) as.character(c) else c]`. If `c` were a character vector, it would use it directly. If it were a factor it would convert it to a character first.

Comment: Also, what is preventing you from always using `as.character()` as a safety? If you were already indexing by a character vector, using `as.character()` would have no effect on it.

Comment: The resulting code would not be portable because it modifies a core R function. This is the same reasoning as why setting `stringsAsFactors=F` globally is a bad idea. Running the same script with another R installation could break it, or worse, produce random results without error.

Wrapping the call like I proposed above this would work either way, but still guard against wrong use.